# Can't get correct spacing around reserved words with semantic package

Tags: spacing, packages

I am working on a programming language semantics text, and decided to use the [semantic](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/semantic/semantic.pdf) package. According to the manual, I can use this:

```
\reservestyle[\mathrel]{\command}{\mathbf}
\command[\mathrel]{skip,while,do,if,then,else}
```

to use, among reserved words, the same spacing that LaTeX uses for relational operators. However, it doesn't seem to work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{braket}

\reservestyle[\mathrel]{\command}{\mathbf}
\command[\mathrel]{skip,while,do,if,then,else}

\begin{document}

\[
\inference[ifTrue]
            {\braket{S_1,s} -> s'}
            {\braket{\<if> b \<then> S_1 \<else> S_2,s} -> s'}
\]

\end{document}
```

The result is this:

[image]

It seems like `\mathrel` isn't working. Did I do anything wrong? Or, is there a way to get reasonable spaces around reserved words, without having to type `\;` several times?

I am using `pdflatex`; the version  is:

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
...
Compiled with libpng 1.6.17; using libpng 1.6.17
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.38.0
```

Comment: Interesting question. I don't see what's wrong, you strictly follow the manual's guidance…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's the other way around:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}
\usepackage{braket}

\reservestyle{\command}{\mathrel}
\command[\mathbf]{skip,while,do,if,then,else}

\begin{document}

\[
\inference[ifTrue]
            {\braket{S_1,s} -> s'}
            {\braket{\<if> b \<then> S_1 \<else> S_2,s} -> s'}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Just to go further into the details, if I do

```
\reservestyle[\mathrel]{\test}{\mathbf}
\test{foo}
\test[\mathrel]{baz}

\expandafter\show\csname<foo>\endcsname
\expandafter\show\csname<baz>\endcsname
```

as suggested by the package, I get

```
> \<foo>=macro:
->\mathbf {\mathrel {foo}}.

> \<baz>=macro:
->\mathbf {\mathrel {baz}}.
```

and it's clear what goes wrong about spacing.

It's an apparent bug in the definition of `\@xdefineReserved`, where the commands `\@@formating` and `\@@spacing` are swapped.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{semantic}

\makeatletter
\def\@xdefineReserved#1[#2]#3\END{%
  \def\reserved@a{#2}%
  \ifx \reserved@a\empty \toks0{#1}\else \toks0{#2} \fi
    \expandafter\edef\csname\expandafter<#1>\endcsname
    {\the\@@spacing{\the\@@formating{\the\toks0}}}}
\makeatother

\reservestyle[\mathrel]{\command}{\mathbf}
\command{skip,while,do,if,then,else}

\begin{document}

$\<if> b \<then> S_1 \<else> S_2,s -> s'$

\end{document}
```

[image]

So the documentation is right, but the implementation went wrong.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. The manual should probably be fixed, though...

Comment: Its last update dates back to 2003… However, the addresses of the authors in the documentation still seems to be correct, you can drop them a line.

Comment: @Clément Yes, it's indeed a bug in the package, where two commands got their places traded.

Comment: @Clément Mail sent